# what is the difference between rechtzeitig and pünktlich?

Tags: difference, word-choice, adjective

When they both mean "punctual, on time". Could you please give some examples? Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm afraid you should simply try an online dictionary as [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/rechtzeitig) for this type of question. Short hint *pünktlich* requires an agreed time, while *rechtzeitig* could refer to something like before it started to rain.

Comment: Well, DWDS is only in german. So why not post a full answer in english here?

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: Why invest work to fully answer an off-topic question? Do you question the benefit of mono-lingual dictionaries for the learner of a language? But I guess, most otther online dictionaries would also have helped.

Comment: I don't question the benefit of mono-lingual dictionaries. Anyway, if someone is not fluent in german, a german dictionary might not be sufficient to make them understand the subtle difference between _pünktlich_ and _rechtzeitig_. If you find a dictionary in english answering the question, why don't you link it here? Asking "Why invest work to fully answer an off-topic question?" sounds very convincing, really. But in fact it's a circular argument, because the dissent is about whether the question is off-topic in the first place. I would just propose to be nice to people seeking help here.

Answer (score 4):

*Rechtzeitig* is rather *in time* (i.e. early enough), while *pünktlich* is *punctual*, *on time* (i.e. at the specified time).